# Problem with interrupts

Tags: arduino-uno, led, interrupt, pwm, hc-sr04

Alright. This is what I wanted to do:

Make a circuit and code the arduino such that there are 2 tactile switches, each with a predefined pwm value.
 Whenever any one button is pressed the led should run at that pwm value, until the button is released. There is
 also an ultrasonic sensor on the same arduino that triggers an interrupt at a threshold distance that 
 stops the led. When no button is pressed or the ultrasonic isnt active, the led should run at another pwm value.

Here is the code:(updated)

```
const int trig = 9;
const int echo = 10;
const int redswitch = 2;
const int yellowswitch = 3;
int redled = 6;
int greenled = 5;
volatile int pwm = 50;

volatile bool rs = LOW;      //RS - RED SWITCH
volatile bool ys = LOW;      //YS - YELLOWSWITCH
bool last_rs = LOW;
bool last_ys =  LOW;
volatile long distance=0;
long duration=0;
long temp=0;

void setup(){
  pinMode(trig,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echo,INPUT);
  pinMode(redled,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenled,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redswitch,INPUT);
  pinMode(yellowswitch,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(redswitch), red,CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(yellowswitch), green,CHANGE);

  digitalWrite(greenled,LOW);
  digitalWrite(redled,LOW);
}

boolean debounce(boolean temp,int switchPin)
{
  boolean current = digitalRead(switchPin);
  if (temp != current)
  {
    delay(5);
    current = digitalRead(switchPin);
  }
  return current;
}

void loop(){


  //Ultrasonic sensor's distance calculation
  digitalWrite(trig,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);

  digitalWrite(trig,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trig,LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(echo, HIGH);
  temp = duration * 0.0343 / 2;
  noInterrupts();
  distance = temp;
  rs = debounce(last_rs,redswitch);
  ys = debounce(last_ys,yellowswitch);
  last_rs = rs;
  last_ys = ys;
  if(distance>8)interrupts();

  Serial.println(distance);  
  analogWrite(redled,pwm);
  analogWrite(greenled,pwm);
}

void red(){

  if(rs == HIGH) pwm = 150;
  else pwm = 0;


}

void green(){

  if(ys == HIGH) pwm = 250;
  else pwm = 0;

}
```

Now, when the arduino is connected to my laptop, led runs at the a particular value. But whenever I press a button they go off. Can you help me find out what's wrong here?

Comment: remove the `constrain(pwm,0,255);`. it does nothing. function `constrain` **returns** first parameter if the value is in constraints or one if the constraints if the value is outside

Comment: you code has too many problems. you use one variable for both outputs. you don't debounce the buttons. you reset PWM in every loop (you don't let it run). and I would say the whole concept of reading the buttons with interrupt is wrong

Comment: @Juraj. I use one variable for both outputs because I want both leds to have same pwm value. About deboucing, I forgot that completely. Sorry. And I dont understand this - " you reset pwm in every loop". where do I do that? i am not resetting pwm in loop(). Reading buttons with interrupt - I was following an online tutorial. I'm totally new to arduino. It would be immensely helpful if you could be a bit more clear and precise.

Comment: but you set pwm to 0 if one of the buttons is not pushed. PWM runs once started. it should do high, low, high,low,high... but if you start it again and again, it does high, and again high and high. interrupts are good for very short events. people hold the buttons long

Comment: I think that interrupts are the the correct way to go. It enables you to do all sorts of slow stuff in your main loop, while you buttons still works. Do not do any read or write in your interrupt functions - you already know the button has been pushed!, and the write happens in your main loop. Do nothing else than change the state of volatile variables. Add debounce.

Comment: @hpekristinsen and Juraj. Thanks a lot for that. I will do what you said and will update the code. I will add debounce. And Juraj, people won't hold the buttons long in this case. this is a task given to me and they aren't supposed to do that. And one more thing, should I use HIGH or RISING inside attachInterrupt() I dont quite get the difference

Answer (score 1):

Look at these lines:

```
distance = temp;
duration = pulseIn(echo,HIGH);
distance = duration * 0.0343 /2;
```

Here is what they do:

- The first line sets the variable `distance` to zero (that's the value
  of `temp`).
- The second line waits for the ultrasonic pulse to reach the target,
  bounce against it and come back, while at the same time timing the
  whole trip. This can take a long time (several milliseconds). Chances
  are your program spends *most* of its time executing this line.
- The third line sets the variable `distance` to something sensible.

This means `distance` is zero most of the time (while the second line
executes). When the interrupt fires, there is a very high probability
for the interrupt handler to find a zero distance, and thus to set `pwm`
to zero.

Simple fix: never set `distance` to an unreasonable value. Leave it's
value alone until you have a new distance measurement ready, and only
then update that variable. In other words, just remove the first of
those three lines.

But there is a catch now. The variable is four bytes long, and updating
it takes four instructions. There is a small probability that the
interrupt fire *in between* these instructions. When that happens, the
interrupt handler finds the `distance` variable half-updated, with a mix
of bytes from the previous and the current distance measurements. This
is called a “race condition”, and is one of the worst kind of bugs you
can meet, because it is very hard to systematically reproduce.

The fix to the race condition is to update the variable with interrupts
disabled. The wrong way to do it is:

```
duration = pulseIn(echo, HIGH);
noInterrupts();
distance = duration * 0.0343 / 2;
interrupts();
```

This is bad because interrupts are blocked during the distance
calculation, which is too much. The right way is this:

```
duration = pulseIn(echo, HIGH);
temp = duration * 0.0343 / 2;
noInterrupts();
distance = temp;
interrupts();
```

Now interrupts are blocked only while writing the `distance` variable.

Personally I don't think it is such a great idea to read the buttons
with interrupts. Buttons are extremely slow peripherals. If you make
your code non-blocking, your `loop()` will always be fast enough to deal
with them. Handling the buttons in `loop()` means you don't have to
worry about all the bugs that can easily sneak into interrupt-driven
code, like the above mentioned race condition.

---

**Edit**: In the original version of your code, interrupts were used to
read the switches. In the edited version, you added a debouncer, and you
don't need interrupts anymore. In fact, the way this version uses
interrupts makes no sense at all. The most problematic bit is the fact
that this code can disable interrupts for arbitrarily long times. This
is not good, and you should be aware that the Arduino's timekeeping
functions rely on interrupts to perform their job.

I suggest you just remove from this code every single line where you see
the word “interrupt” (singular or plural), and you replace

```
if(distance>8)interrupts();
```

by

```
if (distance > 8) {
    red();
    green();
}
```

or, to streamline things a little bit, by

```
if (distance > 8) {
    if (ys == HIGH) pwm = 250;
    else if (rs == HIGH) pwm = 150;
    else pwm = 0;
}
```

Comment: I updated the code in the question. Please check it. There is a great improvement. But right now, the problem seems to be that the code does exactly opposite to what i want. The led glows at a particular pwm value when no button is pressed. When it is pressed, it turns off. i want it to happen vice versa. And for this part **There is also an ultrasonic sensor on the same arduino that triggers an interrupt at a threshold distance that stops the led** -  I use `if(distance>8)interrupts()`. Is this the right way to go?

Comment: @Kishore: see amended answer.

Comment: the thing is I'm learning arduino right now. this is like a task that has been given to me. I have to use interrupts in this code. That is compulsory. I myself have another version of the code where i don't use interrupts and it still does the job. But I have to do the same thing with the use of interrupts. So, I can't remove them.

Comment: @Kishore: Then forget about my edit, and follow the path given in the first part of my answer. You will have to remove your `debounce()` function and find a algorithm suitable for interrupt-driven debouncing. An interesting problem in itself.